# PHP:Send an attachment in PHP mailer

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a attached file to the user along mail

I am using PHP mailer library

```
        $mail->AddAddress($pr_email);
        $mail->Subject = "Activate your account";
        $mail->AddAttachment($data);
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body =$message;

        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
        }
```

Where the `$data` is an image uploaded by user  here how i am reading the value of file and storing in $data variable

```
   $tmpName  = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
   $fp     = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
   $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
   $data = addslashes($data);
   fclose($fp);
```

Unfortunately i am able to receive only message text i am not receiving the attached file along the mail

Please tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: My first thought would be to check the arguments for `AddAttachment()` - you are providing raw binary data, but maybe it is expecting a file path?

Answer (score 1):

```
AddAttachment($path,$name,$encoding,$type);
```

example

```
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment
```

for more information and attach other type attachment [check this link](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/UsefulTutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide the file path to `AddAttachment`.

```
$mail->AddAttachment($tmpName, $file_name);
```

[Check here](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#File_Attachments_PHP_Mail_PHPMailer).

Comment: @xda..  $tmpName  = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];  from here i am getting the file path now when i am doing  $mail->AddAttachment($tmpName, 'Anything');
 Then still it is not working ?